# How to create Data access layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, wcf, data-access-layer

I have two projects wcf service and a web site, both will use a common database. So I want to write a data access layer which will use in both and contains entity data model.
So now my question is, how to do that, what kind of project template i use for DAL, and where to create db, right now it remains locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that you want it in a different DLL which you can reference from both projects. The easiest way to do this is by creating a new project of type [Class Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/319950/Creating-your-own-library-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I have added a class library and created entity model inside it. Than I used the reference in my service, but I am getting error message "No connection string named 'LicenseDbEntities' could be found in the application config file."

Comment: You should add the connection string LicenseDbEntities to the project you're calling the library from. If you think it's there try loading it manually through ConfigurationManager.ConnectionSTrings["LicenseDbEntities"]

Comment: It worked for service, but I did the same thing for my website. And on configuring gridivew data source I got a error saying "The metadata specified in the connectionstring could not be loaded".

Comment: Have you referenced the data access project from the website?